# PHP if statement inside div. No Repeat

Tags: php, database, html, if-statement

I have a database run by the gigpress Wordpress plugin.

This links to a related wordpress post, that will then display related dates(infinite number) and venues(5 venues).

I have successfully filtered the data by venue and wrapped the output in a div...

```
<div class="gigpress-related-park"> 
<?php if ( $showdata['venue'] == "VENUENAME" ) 
{echo "<div class=\"gigpress-related-item\">"; 
echo $showdata['date_long']; echo $showdata['venue']; 
echo "</div>"; } ?>
</div>
```

What I need to do, is create a div(vertical column) for each venue, then display the dates in that div. But when ever I try to wrap the above php in a div, the div is just repeated along with the output.

Sorry I am being vague I have no other way to word my issue.

Live examples.
http://www.gocompletely.com/toni-warne/ <- This event has one venue, should appear in a column.
http://www.gocompletely.com/best-of-british-wrestling/ <-This event is at multiple venues, does not fit columns only floats left.

Thanks! Let me know if I need to provide any more details I will do my best to do so.

***EDIT More info***
I need the code above to result in the below:

```
<div class="gigpress-related-park">
<div class="gigpress-related-item">
1st July, 2012Southport
2nd July, 2012Southport
3rd July, 2012Southport
</div>
</div>
<div class="gigpress-related-park">
<div class="gigpress-related-item">
1st July, 2012Brean Sands
2nd July, 2012Brean Sands
3rd July, 2012Brean Sands
</div>
</div>
```

I hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is an effective float on: `.gigpress-related-park`
I guess that removing it should fix the problem.

Also make sure you clear all floats since thats the most common mistake.

Comment: Sorry Sorry, I might not have been specific enough. The `code`.gigpress-related-park should float left and has now has a clear on it. The problem can be seen more on the best of british wrestling link.  Each column should have it's own park. This is a php issue, as I can't seem to prevent the containing div from repeating.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `clear:left;` on `.gigpress-related-park` css class, that should help.

Comment: There is an already added `float: left` which just have to be removed!